# AndroidAppHelper.currentApplication() returned null

Tags: nullpointerexception, android-context, xposed

I called `AndroidAppHelper.currentApplication()` in my Xposed module, but it returned `null`. In the documentation, it's said that

> the first application that was initialized will be returned.

Is it because of this? The app I'm hooking has 3 processes and I filtered the 2 that are irrelevent.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily for me there is a shortcut: since I'm hooking `android.app.Application`'s `attach` method, I can get the context simply by calling `param.thisObject`. I hooked the `attach` method because otherwise I couldn't find all the classes of the target package (they are not loaded outside the hook).